# Como eliminar el ultimo elemento que se ingreso en la lista (JAVA)

Tags: java

Hasta el momento este es mi codigo del metodo eliminar en forma de Pila.

```
public void eliminarPila() {
        if (ultimo != null) {
            if (ultimo.siguiente != null) {
                System.out.println("Reproduciendo... " + ultimo.nombreCancion);
                ultimo = primero.siguiente;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Reproduciendo... " + ultimo.nombreCancion);
                ultimo = null;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No existen canciones en la lista... ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria la pregunta? si esto es un pila, cumple con que es FIFO, entonces tenes que sacar siempre lo que esta primero, y lo segundo pasa a primero

Comment: Estás hablando de lista y pila como si fueran la misma cosa, cuando no lo es. No queda claro si quieres eliminar de una pila o de una lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada, secundar la sugerencia de ManuelC Perez respecto a que deberías echar un vistazo a los conceptos generales de estructuras de datos.

Si me permites, hago un par de reflexiones sobre lo que propones:

**1.- Elección de la estructura**

Cuando vas a manejar datos, lo primero que debes plantearte es **qué vas a hacer** con esos datos y, en función de eso, **elegir la estructura que mejor se adapte** a los requerimientos del problema a resolver. Por el ejemplo de código que has puesto, parece ser que quieres manejar una lista de canciones de un reproductor. Desde luego es algo que se puede hacer con una pila, pero ¿realmente quieres hacerlo así?

Las pilas son estructuras de datos que, independientemente de la implementación, sólo te permiten acceder al dato que está en la cima de la pila y a ningún otro. Este tipo de estructura de dato corresponde con la estructura LIFO (last in, first out; el último en entrar es el primero en salir). Uno de los múltiples usos que tiene es guardar el resultado de recorridos inversos o análisis sintáticos, por poner algún ejemplo.

En primer lugar, decirte que Java ya posee una clase tipo pila que es la clase [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). Como puedes ver, los métodos que dispone son muy pocos, acordes con el funcionamiento de una pila de datos. Lo importante es que tengas en cuenta que una pila sólo puede interactuar con el elemento que está en la cima de la pila (cuando pienses en pila, piensa en apilar). Las operaciones fundamentales son push (añadir **a la cima** de la pila), pop (extraer y eliminar el elemento que está **en la cima** de la pila), y peek (acceder sin eliminar al elemento **de la cima** de la pila).

El resto de operaciones son accesorias a la estructura para saber cuántos elementos hay y a que profundidad o distancia hay un elemento en la pila. Sobre la conveniencia de implementar estos métodos hay discusiones al respecto, pero no vienen al caso.

Volviendo a tu código: No hay nada que prohiba utilizar una pila para una lista de canciones pero ¿realmente quieres que una lista de reproducción esté en una pila? ¿Qué pasaría si quieres una reproducción aleatoria? ¿O reproducción en bucle de toda la lista? Intuitivamente hablando, no parece que esa sea la estructura que quieres.

Otros compañeros comentan estructuras FIFO (firs in, first out; el primero en entrar es el primero en salir), cuyo nombre común es Cola (piensa en la cola del super, el primero que llega es al primero que atienden). Las operaciones básicas de las colas son, genéricamente, enqueue (poner en cola -**al final** de la cola-), dequeue (sacar de la cola -**del principio** de la cola-), get (acceder, sin sacar de la cola -**únicamente al primero** de la cola-) pero, nuevamente tampoco parece ser la estructura que buscas, ya que tenemos los mismos problemas que con la pila. Igual que antes, indicarte que Java ya dispone de varias clases de cola, cuyo uso es extensísimo dentro de la programación, citando como ejemplo genérico la clase abstracta [AbstractQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html), la cual es lo suficientemente sencilla como para hacerse una idea de las operaciones básicas de una cola. Indicarte que es abstracta porque hereda de AbstractCollection los métodos abstractos *iterator* y *size*, los cuales tendrías que implementar tú, que serás la que internamente sepa cómo está implementada la clase. Esta clase es un buen ejemplo de cómo utilizar las herramientas que ya te da Java y personalizarlas según tus necesidades.

Piensa en ambas estructuras como una manera obligatoria de seguir un orden en la obtención de los datos (LIFO ó FIFO). Para rizar más el rizo, te diré que tanto una pila como una cola se puede implementar, internamente, como una lista o como un array; dependerá del tipo de recorrido que quieras realizar, si quieres limitar el espacio o que crezca indefinidamente, etc.

En resumen, una lista de reproducción debería permitir el acceso aleatorio a cualquiera de los elementos, pero ninguna de las dos estructuras están hechas para eso, por lo que, probablemente, deberías reconsiderar utilizar una pila como estructura de datos para una lista de reproducción.

**2.- Estructura independiente de los datos**

Lo genial de las estructuras de datos es que, respecto de la implementación, son totalmente independientes de los datos que almacenes en ellos. Una pila puede almacenar el tipo de datos que tú quieras y la estructura siempre va a dar la misma respuesta, con total independencia de lo que haya dentro.

Entiendo, con el código que adjuntas, que estás escribiendo un método que trata de manejar una pila de datos, sin embargo añades mensajes que vinculan los datos al comportamiento de la pila de modo que cuando quieres eliminar un elemento de la pila devuelves el mensaje por consola "reproduciendo...". La implementación del código eliminarPila tiene que devolver y eliminar el elemento de la cima de la pila. Absolutamente nada más. El tipo de elemento que haya en la pila o lo que vayas a hacer con él es irrelevante.

Posiblemente más importante que repensar la estructura de datos que vas a usar (que en caso incorrecto hace que las operaciones sean más complejas y por lo tanto ralentizan la ejecución del código) es que te replantees cómo estás realizando el código.

Si dentro de la estructura de datos introduces información sobre los datos que va a manejar estás obviando los fundamentos de programación más básicos. El primero y más evidente es la reutilización del código: esta pila sólo te valdrá para una función muy concreta, de modo que si quieres implementar otra pila en otra parte del código tendrás que volver a programarla de nuevo, con la pérdida de tiempo y riesgo de cometer errores que ello implica. Si algo estupendo tiene la POO es que, si haces una cosa bien, te vale para muchos usos sin modificar una sóla línea de código y no sólo a tí sino que tu código lo podrá implementar cualquier otro programador que necesite resolver el mismo problema usando tu estructura. Directamente relacionado con esto está la refactorización del código. Suponte que durante el desarrollo de tu programa te das cuenta de que podrías mejorar el código de tu pila; si has duplicado tu código 10 veces en tu programa tendrás que realizar los cambios en 10 sitios del programa... nuevamente más esfuerzo y más posibilidad de cometer errores. Imagínate que eso, en vez de con una pila, lo haces con otra estructura o algoritmo más complejo. Esto ocurre generalmente cuando se obvia otro de los fundamentos de programación más básico todavía y tiene que ver con la fase de diseño (en la que aún no has escrito ni una sóla línea de código): la modularización cuya síntesis es "divide y vencerás". Un problema se subdivide en problemas más pequeños, tan pequeños como sea posible de modo que cada solución reciba una y sólo una de las partes del problema, lo resuelva y devuelva la solución. De este modo podrás localizar con más facilidad errores (depuración) y podrás mejorar el código mucho más fácilmente (refactorización). Estos son los dos grandes demonios de cualquier proyecto, hasta el punto de que han hecho fracasar muchos de ellos.

Desconocemos el resto del código, pero pueden verse claramente muchos aspectos que deberías repensar y estudiar más detenidamente. Si no pones unos buenos fundamentos en tus primeros proyectos los siguientes te resultarán casi inabarcables.

Por dejarte una solución (hay muchas posibles), mi consejo es:

1.- Si realmente vas a crear una lista de reproducción, utiliza un array como base de partida. Es sólido y el tiempo de acceso a cada elemento es unitario (orden constante). Si necesitas que crezca indefinidamente, utiliza un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Es más lento cuando añades elementos que superan el límite del array interno pero sólo ocurre cada ciertos elementos (amortización) pero a la hora de acceder a los datos el tiempo sigue siendo unitario.

2.- Si lo que realmente quieres hacer es implementar tu propio diseño de pila o lista: PARA. Permíteme el atrevimiento, pero si lo que quieres hacer es aprender a diseñar una pila, te recomiendo encarecidamente que dejes de picar código y repases los fundamentos de programación (programación estructurada, acoplamiento y cohesión, modularización, reutilización del código...) y por supuesto estructuras de datos básicas. A programar se aprende programando (como cualquier habilidad) pero hay cosas que, como concepto general, tienes que tener claras. Ya buscarás cómo se programa, que será diferente en cada lenguaje, pero el concepto de la estructura, su funcionamiento general y sus funciones básicas es imprescindible que lo tengas medianamente claro. Te aseguro que, con esto claro, tú mismo responderás la pregunta que planteas.

Sea lo que sea lo que estés haciendo, no te rindas ni te frustres. Ánimo e insiste y sobre todo, coge buenas costumbres desde el primer minuto. Para hacer las cosas de forma "heterodoxa" siempre hay tiempo (y puede ser bastante divertido). Aquí estamos para ayudarnos unos a otros y créeme que resolverte el problema concreto que planteas, en este caso, no sería ayudarte.

Un saludo.

P.D.: Te dejo un par de libros de referencia.
https://pearson.es/espa%C3%B1a/TiendaOnline/c%C3%B3mo-programar-en-java-9ed-
http://pearson.es/espa%C3%B1a/TiendaOnline/piensa-en-java-4ed

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que estaría bien que hicieras es leer un poco la documentación de Java, en lo referente al trato de listas.

Aquí te dejo documentación:

- [Como añadir a una lista](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-)
- [Como eliminar un objeto de una lista](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

Respecto a tu código, se parece más a un pseudo-codigo que a codigo java, propiamente dicho. Ya que usas métodos que no existen. Además, si pudieses proporcionar que tipo de objetos son 'ultimo' y 'siguiente', estaría bien.

Para tu pregunta, si lo que quieres es borrar el último que entró, podrias usar el método remove, que necesita el index del objeto a borrar; al ser el último, usas el método size() que poseen las listas en java y le restas 1.

Sería algo así:

```
ultimo.remove(ultimo.size()-1);
```

Comment: Hola Manuel, aunque en el titulo Maricela pregunta por una lista, en su codigo utiliza las Pilas y tal como ha dicho @gbianchi se rige por la idea de FIFO(First In , First Out) [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_in,_first_out)

Comment: Pero hay fos tipos de pila, FIFO y LIFO, al hacer referencia 'ultimo elemento que entró en la lista', me hace pensar que es LIFO(Last In, First Out), de ahí mi solución.